# Pass JSON data as parameter - RequestURITooLarge

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, webrick

I'm trying to send almost large json data as a parameter to one of my controllers in my rails project as below:

```
<%= link_to "Select", channel_path(:hit => "#{json_data["clips"]}") %>
```

but I get:

```
[2014-02-24 10:34:38] ERROR WEBrick::HTTPStatus::RequestURITooLarge
[2014-02-24 10:34:38] ERROR TypeError: can't convert nil into an exact number
    /home/vagrant/htdocs/htdocs/cac-verticals/.gems/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/calculations.rb:326:in `-'
    /home/vagrant/htdocs/htdocs/cac-verticals/.gems/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/calculations.rb:326:in `minus_with_duration'
    /home/vagrant/htdocs/htdocs/cac-verticals/.gems/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/calculations.rb:337:in `minus_with_coercion'
    /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/accesslog.rb:111:in `setup_params'
    /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:219:in `access_log'
    /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `run'
    /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

I also tried to use `thin` instead of `webrick` but thin also complains about the large request.

Any recommendations? tnx.

Comment: I think there is a 2kb limit to URLs (may depend on browser and/or web server). You may need to do a `post` instead.

Comment: Its the same also with `POST` request

Comment: You must also move the information into a data segment (basically do a form post). The URL itself will otherwise still be too large.